# How to find out the command to add program to session startup programs?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, startup-applications

I'd like to add empathy to the list of programs to start up when starting an session, i looked at this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup but I don't think this is adapted to 12.04 (see section "How to find the appropriate startup command")

So, how can i find out the command for a program to add to startup programs?

Comment: This answer may help: http://askubuntu.com/a/126423/3940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out the command for any program you should type this in the terminal-

> ```
> whereis *application name*
> ```

For example,

If you want to find out the command to run *Gedit* the type in the terminal-

> `whereis gedit`
>
> and you will get an output like this-
>
> ```
> gedit: /usr/bin/gedit /usr/lib/gedit /usr/bin/X11/gedit /usr/share/gedit /usr/share/man/man1/gedit.1.gz
> ```

out of that,the very first path you see-`/usr/bin/gedit` is the path to the executable file...Which should be added in the startup applications list.. :)

Hope it helps

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

With

```
ps x -o args
```

you can get a list of running processes including the arguments that have been passed to the command.