# How to Add PCloud in startup applications?

Tags: 14.04, cloud, startup-applications

I am using PCloud (cloud storage) on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. To avoid any misunderstanding, I want to clarify that PCloud is just another Dropbox like cloud storage solution. I want to start this application automatically every time I log in. To do this I've searched the binary file in the "/" directory of my machine, but I've found no binary files for PCloud!!!

How can I add PCloud in startup applications?

Comment: Is this a background service? Also, do you want to start it when the machine boots, or when you log in?

Comment: @AndroidDev This is not a background service. Actually, I want to start it when I log in.

Comment: the executable is named psyncgui and is located under /usr/bin/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start applications automatically on login?](/q/48321) paired with [How to find out the terminal command of an application?](/q/126268/175814)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the command:

> Most default applications will have a `.desktop` file located in
>   `/usr/share/applications`.
>
> To find out about the corresponding terminal command that will be run
>   when launching one of these applications open the file browser
>   Nautilus and right click on the application's icon to select
>   Properties in the context menu. [Then, look at the "command" box]

- Taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application)

---

Then:
Dash > Startup Applications

Add a new entry, and in the "command" box, put the command to launch this program from CMDline.

**Please note, it may not start instantly after logon. It might be 30 seconds before it opens.**

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I can't find the "command" to launch this program, that's the main problem.

Comment: @tuxtu See edited answer.