# How to get the command for existing launcher entries?

Tags: command-line, launcher, 16.04

How do I get the start command from an existing launcher entry on 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launcher entries are `.desktop` files stored in `/usr/share/applications` or in `~/.local/share/applications`. So you could just use `cat` on these files.

Comment: I found the right file in  "~/.local/share/applications" but not in "/usr/share/applications". So the solution doesn't exist in ["the exact duplicate of this question"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application). Please remove the "marked as duplicate" Tag!!!