# Which command is executed when selecting an entry in Unity dock?

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm searching for a way to find out which particular command is executed when I select a program from the Unity Dock?

Example: I just installed the Webstorm IDE and I can start this using the dock. (Super-Key, type in web and then select the Webstorm icon...) Everything works fine.

Another example: when I type "pdf" in the dock it offers me some applications. The names are even localized and I have no clue to what program it really points to. I'd like to find out what program really hides behind the localized name "Dokumentenbetrachter"

However, I'd like to see the command that is executed when I click that icon. (On Windows, I do a right click on the icon, select properties and the system shows me the way it goes...

How is this possible with the Ubuntu dock? Where are these settings stored?

(The solution given in [How to find out the terminal command of an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application) is only part of the truth. There are more locations for *.desktop files. They are given now inthe accdepted answer.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out the terminal command of an application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application)

Comment: There's a few issues here. The location of `.desktop` files is irrelevant. These can exist in any directory.  MPLAB IDE for instance, places its shortcuts into `/opt` directory.  As for  the *real program that hides behind the localized name* may also be different from what stated in the file ( for instance , it may be a wrapper script that merely sets up environment and calls a completely different app ).  There's lots to consider. Real program that runs can only be determined by the program class it may or may not report to x server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons you see in the dash are defined in .desktop files. They live in two locations:

For system wide ones: `/usr/share/applications/`

For user specific ones: `/home/user/.local/share/applications/` (These override the system ones.)

You can use an application called 'Alacarte' to edit them via a GUI or just find them in Nautilus, right click, and click 'Properties'. You can also edit them manually using Gedit.

Comment: There seems to be a third location: `/usr/local/share/applications`
At least there I eventually found my WebStorm.desktop file.