# Simple way to run any program as root

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

Is there a simple way to run any program as root from the unity launcher?

I often run into situations where I'd like to run a program as root.
E.g. today wanted to run the `Disk Usage Analyzer` as root since it only gives me half the information otherwise.

What I was looking for was some context-menu entry in the unity launcher or in the "task bar" (how is the quick launcher at the right officially called?) but didn't find any.

What I ended up with, was using Google to find out the name of the `Disk Usage Analyzer` command which is `baobab` which I then started in the bash using `gksudo`.

Alternatively I'd be happy to have some easy way to find the internal command of an application which is shown in the unity launcher. E.g. `baobab` for the `Disk Usage Analyzer`.

Comment: Related: [How to find out the terminal command of an application?](http://askubuntu.com/q/126268/329173)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, looking through the answers gives me the impression that there is no "easy" way to accomplish this. I guess using Google is faster than all of those approaches... What I'm actually missing here is to achieve this from within the launcher. Again by a context menu with some entries like `Go to location`, `Properties`, `Open as Root` to prevent firing up Nautilus etc...