# How to find where a quick launch icon is pointing to

Tags: unity, launcher

When I hover over a quick launch icon, the name of the underlying application is displayed.  But how can I find what application is really being invoked?

In a MS Windows context, I would right click the icon and select Properties - then the path of the file to be executed would be shown.

This came up because my "Files" quick launch icon would do nothing, and it took some considerable research to realize that icon was actually linked to /usr/bin/nautilus.

Comment: It is also a right click context. We use the *Properties* entry for more information on files. If you had put a `.desktop` file on the desktop you  could use this menu there but usually they are located in other places. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In   GNU/Linux we use `.desktop` files aka "Desktop Entries", they are located at:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

also can be find per user as:

```
~/.local/share/applications/
```

From [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Entries):

> Desktop Entry specification provides a standard for applications to integrate into a desktop environment. Desktop entries are the configuration files that describe how an application is launched and which data it can handle. They also configure how an application appears in a menu with an icon, which is subject to the related menu specification standard.

You can locate them using `locate` command too:

```
locate nautilus.desktop
```

or

```
locate nautilus | grep ".desktop"
```

let's see what is in `nautilus.desktop`:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
NotShowIn=Unity;
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
```

As you see the name is "Files" however it executes `nautilus --new-window %U`. For the command `nautilus` itself as you should know we can use `which` to find out where it is located:

```
$ which nautilus
/usr/bin/nautilus
```

To find them by name you can do as follow, say we want to know by clicking on an icon with the name "Files" which program will be executed:

```
 grep -lRi name=files /usr/share/applications/
```

- -l: show only file names
- -R: recersuve
- -i: in-case sensitive

it will outputs:

```
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
/usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

then I can look into those files for `Exec=` to see which program really will be run.

something like this will do it more convenience:

```
grep -lRi name=files /usr/share/applications/ | xargs grep exec= -i
```

Comment: To give a quick one-liner: